# Can I save a geometry index in pickle file of geometries list in python

Tags: python, pickle, geopandas

I have simple elevation data from a GeoTiff fill that I've read in via Rasterio.  Now I want to use Shapely's STR Tree to get intersects with other points and lines, and the most efficient way would be to store the elevation-attributed lists of geometries as pickles, and load them directly rather than loading and converting a csv of pickle of a pandas geoDataframe (or various similar options).

```
def openPickleFile(filePathName):    
    with open (filePathName, 'rb') as fp:
        return pickle.load(fp)

def writePickleFile(theData,filePathName):    
    with open(filePathName, 'wb') as fp:
        pickle.dump(theData, fp)

thisData = openPickleFile('thisDataFrame.pkl') 
gridGeoms = list(thisData['geometry'])
gridValues = list(thisData['elevation'])
for index, geom in enumerate(gridGeoms):
    gridGeoms[index].idx = gridValues[index] 
writePickleFile(gridGeoms, 'thisGeometryList.pkl')
```

If I `print(gridGeoms[i].idx)` here I get the elevation of geometry `i` as desired.  But if I load the `'thisGeometryList.pkl'` file and do the same thing I get a `'Polygon' object has no attribute 'idx'` error.  I thought the pickle would store the binary data of gridGeoms that includes the added `.idx` attribute.

Is there some option for pickling that will save the `.idx` attribute?
Or is there an alternative format that will save this info and be just as efficient?
(Note: I tried joblib and it also doesn't retain the `.idx` data)

Comment: I would suggest creating another list where you would store idx and saving that as separate pickle

Comment: But I would still have to iterate through both lists and assign the index to the geometry, which is the step I'm trying to avoid in order to speed up the "getting elevation from intersecting grid(s)" process

Comment: Is that Polygon class your code? Is there something special with that variable? Is it a property for example. There seems to be some restrictions how pickle can store data.

Comment: It's the Shapely Polygon class.  I found the ability to add the `.idx` attribute to solve that problem somewhere on Githib, but I can't find it again, nor do I see anything in the docs to support it.  I agree there must be some restrictions on how pickle can store data, but I don't know why it's not storing this data, or how else to save it.